# Deserialize JSON to c# object raising an exception

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

Could you please help me to deserialize the following JSON to c#.

```
[
  {
    "detectedLanguage": {
      "language": "en",
      "score": 10.0
    },
    "translations": [
      {
        "text": "",
        "to": "da"
      },
      {
        "text": "",
        "to": "da"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**I have used the following c# classes for deserialization but getting an exception.**

```
public class DetectedLanguage
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DetectedLanguage detectedLanguage { get; set; }
    public List<Translation> translations { get; set; }
}
```

**My deserialization code is:**

```
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse);
```

**Exception**

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '',
>   line 1, position 1.

Comment: Your JSON represents an array - it starts with `[` and ends with `]`. You're trying to deserialize it as a single `RootObject`. Either get rid of the square brackets at the start and end, or deserialize to a `List<RootObject>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed to List<RootObject> but I am still receiving an exception as  "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
.".

Comment: @Simant: I can't reproduce that. Using your exact classes and JSON, it parses fine. Without knowing anything more than there being a FormatException *somewhere*, it's hard to help further. (Perhaps that's in a separate piece of code?)

Comment: `var json = "[{\"detectedLanguage\":{\"language\":\"en\",\"score\":0},\"translations\":[{\"text\":\"\",\"to\":\"da\"},{\"text\":\"\",\"to\":\"da\"}]}]";


var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);`

works fine

Comment: @IvanSalo I am getting the json  [{\"detectedLanguage\":{\"language\":\"en\",\"score\":0.0},\"translations\":[{\"text\":\"\",\"to\":\"da\"}]}] which is similar to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **score** property is sometimes holding float value but in my c# class, there is datatype **int** which causes the exception. I didn't notice before **@Ivan Salo**'s comment. Changing data type **int** to **float** fixed my issue.I have also used List to deserialize the JSON which is suggested by @Jon Skeet in the comments section.

```
public class DetectedLanguage
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public float score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only part that's needed to answer the question *as asked* is the use of `List`. For the float part to be relevant, it would be better if you'd show an example with that in the JSON. I'd either edit your question in that way, or perhaps delete the whole question; I don't think the Q&A combination provides very much value right now.

Answer (score -3):

Edited as a complete answer:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    public partial class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("detectedLanguage")]
        public DetectedLanguage DetectedLanguage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("translations")]
        public Translation[] Translations { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DetectedLanguage
    {
        [JsonProperty("language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("score")]
        public long Score { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Translation
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("to")]
        public string To { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RootObject
    {
        public static RootObject[] FromJson(string jsonresponse) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(jsonresponse);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = RootObject.FromJson(jsonResponse);
        System.Console.WriteLine(result[0].DetectedLanguage.Language); //outputs "en"
    }
}
```

Comment: While that would be better in terms of being more conventional, the existing structure *works* when deserializing to the right type.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. The request was to help "deserialize the following JSON to c#.", which my code does. It also included for using RootObject as an array.

Comment: The original model code *also* deserialized the JSON. The *only* problem was what it was being deserialized to. Originally the answer didn't show the deserialization at all - it's better now, but the fact that it doesn't have *any* explanation makes it still unhelpful IMO.